# simplied tics expression in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

when I draw a graph using gnuplot, I'd like to print simple way.
such as "1    2     3    4    5   1e6"

In the graph axis just print simple number and end of the graph pring "1e10" like this. I trying to several options, I con't find the solution so far.

below is what I want.

[image]

And I also attached current graph.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
exp_scale=5
set size 0.9,1
set label 1 sprintf("10^%d",exp_scale) at graph 1, graph 0 offset char 1,0
plot "data.dat" u ($1/(10**exp_scale)):2 with l
```